# How to check if an email address exists in Objective C cocoa

Tags: objective-c, email

I have a simple question and that is how do you check if an email exists

I have seen this code on a recent post:

```
- (BOOL) NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString{

    BOOL stricterFilter = YES; 
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
 }
```

My question is, how do I return an action if the BOOL returns YES or NO with an `NSTextField`?

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking since it doesn't seem to be the actual validating of the email address but something else. Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Could you please explain "return an action if the BOOL returns YES or NO with an NSTextField"? I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: You might want to return YES or NO with a label, or a NSLog. It's not possible to check if a specific address is valid, you can only check if it's been typed correctly

Comment: what I mean is, if the syntax is correct. I should in fact say validating email. I want to be something like: if(//returns false){//preform action   }

Comment: So you want to show an alert with "Valid Mail" or an ActivityIndicator with a label "Validating mail.." ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a label that indicates if the email typed correctly has the correct syntax. Like ...@... then if in that syntax, it will preform the true if statement

Comment: let me clarify one last time. All I want is for a label to display invalid email address if typed incorrectly and valid email address if typed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have a label and set the text of the label to an appropriate message if the email is correct or not.

You can run your checking routine every time the user types a new character into the text field by implementing the following `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
   shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
   replacementString:(NSString *)string {

   NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
   if ([self NSStringIsValidEmail:newText]) {
      statusLabel.text = @"Valid.";
   } else {
      statusLabel.text = @"Not a valid email address.";
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem though, I am doing cocoa for mac applications, not iPhone. Can you change this for mac?